# Entering / Davening in a Karaite synagogue

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue, heresy, non-rabbinic-judaism

Is one permitted to enter and/or daven in a Karaite synagogue nowadays (according to Rabbinite law)?

Comment: It seems hard to distinguish between that and a Conservative synagogue. If there is a distinction, I'd love to hear why in an answer.

Comment: @Yishai what?  Kaarites reject the oral law and thus the rabbinic process; Conservative doesn't.  Those seem pretty different.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, my understanding (and again, I'm open to a distinction/correction in an answer) from an Orthodox perspective, Conservatives are also rejecting the oral law. Yes, they have more respect for it than Kaarites, but respect and adherence as a recognition of its divine origin isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Yishai, maybe an answer will address that (or you can ask a followup question).  It's just that your comment strikes me a little wrong -- it comes across to me as "I assert this; feel free to prove me wrong", on a point that the question wasn't really asking about.  I assume this is a communication problem or my lack of perception or something, but that's why I commented.

Comment: @Yishai - I never bothered checking sources (as it's never been relevant) but my understaning has always been that an Orthodox Jews will/should NOT daven in a Conservative synagogue.

Comment: @Yishai I am quite certain that you are incorrect about that. Conservative responsa frequently cite the Talmud. Even if Conservative Judaism rejects the divine origin of the oral law (I don't know whether it does or not), they still accept its validity (and binding status at least to some extent) as a source of Jewish law.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe in his Igros Moshe Even Haezer 2:17 writes one cannothat pray in a conservative temple and one shouldn't even attendo a wedding that takes place there.

The karites are kofrim in regards to the oral Torah see the Rambam in hilchos Tshuvah (however,see Hilchos Mamarim 3:3 where he considers them tinok shinisbos). In his tshuvos he writes that karites cannot be counted in a minyan since they are kofrim in that concept.

It would seem from kal chomer that conservative Jewery which don't deny the oral Torah completely and still one cannot attend their temples ,certainly karites who completely deny the oral Torah one cannot visit their temples. With regard to a heretic being part of a minyan see the Igros Moshe.

Text of the Rambam's Tshuvah:
שו"ת הרמב"ם סימן רסה

שאלה ויורינו בדבר אלה האנשים הנקראים קראים, אם הם באים למושב או לבית מדרש או לבית /הכנסת/ הכניסת ואין באים עמם אלא פחות מעשרה מן הרבנים, המאמינים בתורה שבכתב ושבעל פה, אשר אלה הקראים כופרים בה כפי שזה מפורסם ואינם מאמינים בקבלה, אלא מחזיקים בחיצוניותו של המקרא עם פירושיהם. האם, כשבאים מן הרבנים תשעה אנשים ואינם יכולים להשלים המנין, ישלימו באחד מן הקראין את העשרה להתפלל בציבור או לזולתו מן הענינים, שאין מקיימין מצוותם אלא בעשרה, אם לאו? יבאר לנו באר היטב. וכן אם באו ששה או חמשה רבנים, הישלימו את העשרה באלה הקראים אם לאו? וכן יבאר לנו, המותר באחד מהם הזימון? וכן יבאר לנו מה חייב שליח ציבור שחטא ועבר לפני התיבה במעמדם, כשהם משלימים העשרה, אם זה אסור? וכן יבאר לנו העניינים, שבהם נחלקים הקראים מן הרבנים, ושכרו כפול מן השמים.

התשובה אסור להשלים בהם מנין, לא עשרה ולא שלשה, משום שאינם מודים בחיוב זה (הדבר). והעיקר בזה אומרם בעירוב או ביד מי שאינו מודה בעירוב אינו עירוב. וכל דבר, שמאמינים בחיובו ובחלותו, רשאים אנו להצטרף אליהם בו, וכל מה שאין מאמינים בחיובו ובחלותו, אסורים שיצטרפו בו. וידוע שאינם מאמינים בחיוב הקדושה ולא בחיוב הזימון, ואינם משגיחים במנין עשרה ולא במנין שלשה. ומאחר שאינם מודים בחוקים אלו, אסור לעשות זאת עמהם ולהשלים המנין בהם, אחרת סומכין בדבר על מי שאינו מאמין בו. ומי שעבר לפני התיבה במעמדם, מתרים בו ומונעין אותו מזה, ותו לא. וכתב משה.