# Permissibility of Prayer in a Sabbatean Synagogue

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue, shabbetai-tzvi

Inspired by the [Churva Synagogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurva_Synagogue) of [R. Yehuda HaChassid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_he-Hasid_%28Jerusalem%29) (18th cent.) who was [likely](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93_(%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)#.D7.A9.D7.90.D7.9C.D7.AA_.D7.A9.D7.91.D7.AA.D7.90.D7.95.D7.AA.D7.95) a [Sabbatean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbateans) (not to be confused with the 12th century [rabbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Samuel_of_Regensburg) of the same name), and his congregation which almost certainly included Sabbateans, I ask whether it is permitted to pray in a Sabbatean synagogue.

This in light of the fact that Sabbatean [ideology](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.AA.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.90.D7.9C.D7.95.D7.94.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A9.D7.9C_.D7.A9.D7.91.D7.AA.D7.99_.D7.A6.D7.91.D7.99) included seemingly idolatrous elements.

---

I recognize that the Churva Synagogue in particular has been destroyed (hence the name) and subsequently rebuilt, and thus likely lost whatever its original legal status was. However, this was just the inspiration for the question. The question is **not** asking about the Churva in particular, but rather about Sabbatan sites in general.

Comment: Does anyone care to explain the comment-less downvote?

Comment: see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33799/entering-davening-in-a-karaite-synagogue?rq=1